# How to allow access to camera in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I wanted to load a website in Android WebView which uses a device camera. But on Android WebView I'm not able to access the device camera

When I run: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })` in JavaScript It does not ask for permission for camera and gives following error:

[image]

I have added the following permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Thank You!!

Comment: And? Is working now?

Answer (score 1):

You will still need to request the user grants permission for your app to use the camera. I don't think you can request permission for this within your WebView (you can [implement a JavaScript interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#UsingJavaScript) though to trigger it via your web app), so you will need to do it natively in Java/Kotlin on your app (maybe you want to do this on boot)

You can request permission by doing something like this

```
    requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CODE)
```

You can see more info on requesting permissions to use hardware on Android [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)